# 8th Wall Unity Android not showing object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, 8thwall-xr

Was trying the Unity Sample, follow every instruction. Able to compile and installed. But no object was shown anywhere.

Using Unity 5.5 and 5.6 and Xiaomi Mi5

Possible a sample APK?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information or a screenshot of how your project is setup? Did you remember to add the XRController to your scene?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Multithreaded Rendering is disabled:

https://docs.8thwall.com/xr/unity/#disable-mulththreaded-rendering

Also, a prefab in the sample unity project had a dependency on Blender, which has since been fixed:

https://github.com/8thwall/xr-unity/issues/9